# How to allow use of private member pointer as template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, friend, g++4.8, member-pointers

I have a class (`User` in the example below) that derives from a base class (`Base`), passing a third class type (`Used`) and a member pointer within that class as template parameters to the base class.

What do I need to do within `Used` (i.e., what do I need to befriend) such that the pointed to data member can be private?

```
class User;

template <typename T, int T::*member>
class Base {

};

class Used {
    // Befriend everything there is.
    friend class User;
    template <typename T, int T::*member> friend class Base;
    // The variable that should be accessible.
    int i;
};

// error: ‘int Used::i’ is private
class User : public Base<Used, &Used::i> {

};
```

[(Not) working example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/s4sx1v)

Edit: Given that this seems to work on newer versions of GCC, how can I work around the problem given g++ 4.8.4?

Comment: [Works just fine on a more recent version of GCC and on Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/303ed2b10e4378f5). [Just befriending `User` is sufficient](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a955b9ddf9030b29).

Comment: Works for me with g++ 4.9.3.

Comment: Looks like a manifestation of https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59482.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for the link, that looks very similar to the problem indeed. Any ideas for a workaround that does not involve making `i` public?

Comment: Something like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ziICOE8RtNJAYq5s)?

Comment: @T.C. Looks promising, I'll give it a try. Thanks!